# FontFace for jquery appended text

Tags: jquery, font-face

I'm doing a rotating banner on my site. This banner is a mix of images and text. I got it working great except that my @fontface font is not working with the text.

I'm doing something like this for the rotation:

```
$("#container div").first().appendTo('#container').fadeOut(5000);
$("#container div").first().fadeIn(5000);
```

So I'm assuming it has something to do with the appended text after the font is applied. Or something. I'm fairly new to fontface, so this may be something I'm doing wrong.

Relevant CSS:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'OpenSansRegular';
    src: url('fonts/OpenSans-Regular-webfont.eot');
    src: url('fonts/OpenSans-Regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('fonts/OpenSans-Regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('fonts/OpenSans-Regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('fonts/OpenSans-Regular-webfont.svg#OpenSansRegular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}

#homecontainer span {
    float: right;
    display:block;
    font-family:OpenSansRegular,Ariel, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

The text is showing up as Ariel. The rest of the text that uses this font works fine. Any ideas?

Comment: I did try changing the font to something else to make sure I was using the right css reference. That worked fine.

Comment: I think you meant Arial the font, not Ariel the mermaid :)

Comment: Are you sure that you got you selectors right? In CSS you have `#homecontainer span` but in your JS it's `#container div`

Comment: The span is inside the div. The div is what is rotating, but its the span that is holding the text that needs styled. And yes, Arial. That was just a typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
font-family:OpenSansRegular,Ariel, Helvetica, sans-serif;
```

to

```
font-family:'OpenSansRegular',Ariel, Helvetica, sans-serif;
```

Also double check your CSS selection with something obnoxious `font-size:50px;color:pink;` to make sure you are actually applying that font to the proper region.